# Android push doesn't work for one Parse.com app, while working for another

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have an Android application with two `Parse.com` environments: `dev` and `prod`. The codebase is exactly the same: all the configurations in the `Android Manifest` file, and the code to subscribe to the push are the same.

But for some reason when I do a push it works for the `dev`, and doesn't for the `prod`.

This is what I'm doing: I'm going to the `Push` tab on the site, and click `Send Push`. Then I select Segment > Android > MyNewAndroidCannel. It says `This will be sent to 1739 devices.` Then I put in my message and send the push - but the Pushes Sent count is 0.

If I do the same in the `dev` environment everything works fine.

Any idea why would that happen? I can copy all my configuration entries and code to this question but it seems pointless since I know they work / don't work based on something in the definition of the app on `Parse.com`.

When I look at the `Parse.com` app's Push settings they look exactly the same for both the `dev` and `prod` environments.

EDIT: adding info. In my `dev` app the `deviceToken` is populated for Android installations, but in the `prod` app it is not. In the security for the `dev` I have the `Delete` and `Add Fields` options enabled, but in the `prod` they are `disabled`. Is this the problem? Is it safe to allow updating and deleting for the installations?

Comment: Have you checked that the installations in your prod app all have a deviceToken stored in the installations table?

Comment: @BjörnKaiser you're right, none of them do. Why is that? What am I missing? Is there a way to fix it for the installations already in place?

Comment: Oh, I'm seeing as per Hector's response here https://www.parse.com/questions/databrowser-missing-appidentifier-and-devicetoken-data-for-android-devices-whats-wrong is that a deviceToken isn't necessary for Android installations. So I guess we're back to square 1.

Comment: I edited the question with additional info about the deviceToken, and installations security.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problem was that I disabled the `Add fields` on the `installation` object and - I guess - when Parse changed the Android push mechanism they also added a requirement for a `pushType` field.

So the `pushType` was rejected by the `installation` security, the `deviceToken` wasn't populated, and the push failed. Once I added the `pushType` column to the `installation` the pushes started working again.